# Stacks software: Samples empty in Web interface

Tags: mysql, stack

Using a reference genome

Manual:
(http://creskolab.uoregon.edu/stacks/manual/#sfiles)

I did run the following command line:

```
for FILE in $ (ls /home/llcoutinho/Fabio/samples/bam *.); ref_map.pl the T-7-B-1-b chicken_radtags F2-D "Reference aligned genetic map RAD-Tag Samples"-o /home/llcoutinho/Fabio/samples/-s $ FILE; done
```

all outputs are present and accessible from the command line:

```
batch_1.catalog.alleles.tsv, 
batch_1.catalog.snps.tsv, 
batch_1.catalog.tags.tsv, 
.matches.tsv(sample by sample), 
.alleles.tsv(sample by sample), 
.snps.tsv(sample by sample),
.tags.tsv (sample by sample), 
batch_1.haplotypes, 
batch_1.hapstats, 
batch_1.markers, 
batch_1.phistats, 
batch_1.sumstats, 
batch_1.sumstats_summary, 
batch_1.populations, 
ref_map.log
```

but when I access the web:

```
/localhost/stacks/index.php?db=chicken_radtags_
```

All samples output appear, but without information, totally empty
with no "unique stacks" and no "SNPs found"

Comment: please ask one question per question (posting a second one is totally acceptable if they are both valid questions.) Also clarify what it is that you are expecting (sample results) and what it is that you are getting, along with what you try to solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you, the question was edited,